# How to get current PC name?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

I am working on a project and i want to make my project portable.
Connecting java and SQL server 2012 and using PC Name in the connection.In my case it is `Hwl`. 
:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\Hwl:1433;databaseName=dbs","sa","dbase");

Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
```

Now i want to get `PC-Name` (e.g `Hwl` in my case ) on the machine in which that code is running.
I simply want to get the `PC` name and pass that to the `connection string` in each machine where it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following function would return hostname.

```
public String getHostName() {
    String hostName = "";
    try {
        java.net.InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        hostName = addr.getHostName();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
      System.out.println("Hostname can not be resolved");
    }
    return hostName; }
```

Comment: But how i use this in the connection code? `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\PC-Name:1433;databaseName=My_Project","sa","dbase");`

Comment: As in this code, in `PC-Name` i have written my own pc name e.g `Hwll`.

Comment: the variable `hostName` will contain the name of the computer where the java is running is this what you want ?

Comment: Try following code. String hostName = getHostName();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\" + hostName + ":1433;databaseNam‌​e=My_Project","sa","dbase"); If this is what you needed accept the answer else write down comment.